# Why the memory usage of the server increases when running the grpc's greeter_server.py example?

Tags: python, memory, grpc

I am new to grpc. Then I just runned the demo of helloword server, the resident memory usage of server growed and growed.

I tested it on Linux, installed grpc by pip, `grpcio==1.4.0, grpcio-tools==1.4.0`, both python 2.7.12 and 3.6.1.

I just add one line in [greeter_client.py](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_client.py), then the codes just like below:

```
def run():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)
    for i in range(100000):
        response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
        print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
```

the `ps aux` link of result:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6399856/28417768-e8171cd4-6d8b-11e7-9cf1-817c33641f63.png

I would appreciate any further information on this, thanks.

Comment: By changing the code, how rapidly (in bytes/second) are you able to cause memory to be leaked? Does increasing the message size increase the size of the leak?

Does the leak level off at any point? Are you able to get the process to crash for lack of memory?

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle Thanks for your reply. I added the issue [#11887](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/11887) which was considered as a bug by others, and applied [#12249](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/12249), the memory did not increase any more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6619 this has been raised in the past.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I has read the issue before. Just now, I tested [the demo](https://github.com/zj8487/helloworld) mentioned above. Unluckly, the rss of server process increased, 20k  to 40k in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

After the trying period, I found a solution for the question.
Applying the [djanku's commit](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/12249/commits/c5e6cefc8d95031983e8dbfd8ece370ac618cc9d) on github of grpc, the memory above did not increase any more.

I also expect that it will be resolved in next release version of grpcio.